# ¿Es posible crear un acortador url que al cargar la dirección original no la muestre?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, nodejs

Quiero saber si existe posibilidad de crear un acortador url tipo bit.ly que al cargar la dirección original no la muestre si no que se quede en **bit.ly/sHgdetc...**

¿Qué lenguajes me permitirían hacer esto?

Comment: @Aprendiz La parte en que pregunta "qué lenguaje debo usar", efectivamente, puede considerarse basada en opiniones. Pero la pregunta inicial era si es posible. En mi respuesta muestro que no, por lo que en el fondo la parte del lenguaje es irrelevante. Propongo editar la pregunta (si al autor le parece bien) para eliminar la cuestión sobre el lenguaje (o reescribirla en todo caso como "¿qué lenguajes me permitirían hacer esto?"), para evitar que la pregunta sea cerrada, pues creo que es interesante.

Comment: entendido y coincido contigo @abulafia

Answer (score 4):

## Respuesta corta

Es imposible.

## Respuesta larga

Un acortador de URLs básicamente toma una URL que tú le des, le aplica un hash para reducirla a unos pocos caracteres, y **almacena ambos resultados**, devolviéndote a ti la versión "corta", pero manteniendo en su base de datos también la versión larga.

Por ejemplo, si le damos esta URL: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282035/es-posible-crear-un-acortador-url-que-al-cargar-la-direcci%c3%b3n-original-no-la-mue`, que es la URL a esta misma pregunta, te devolverá como resultado
`https://bit.ly/​2K3iZqw`. En su base de datos guardará `2K3iZqw` como clave, y la URL original como valor.

Cuando le das la URL "acortada" a otro usuario, y éste la introduce en su navegador (o hace clic sobre ella) la petición irá dirigida obviamente a los servidores de `bit.ly`, pues ese es el nombre del *host* en la URL acortada. La petición hace un GET a la ruta `/2K3iZqw`, por lo que el servidor consulta en su base de datos buscando por esa clave, recupera la URL original, y se la devuelve al navegador en la cabecera `Location`, mediante una respuesta como la siguiente:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Location: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282035/es-posible-crear-un-acortador-url-que-al-cargar-la-direcci%C3%B3n-original-no-la-mue
[Otras cabeceras eliminadas]
```

Es decir, el navegador recibe el **código de redirección 301**, por lo que, obediente, hará una nueva petición a la URL indicada en la cabecera `Location`, que como puedes ver es la URL original.

A partir de aquí la cosa queda ya fuera de la "jurisdicción" del acortador. Puesto que el navegador accede a la dirección original, el navegador la mostrará.

La única forma de evitar esto sería que el servidor que hace de acortador guardara a su vez una copia de la página, para poder servirla (pero esto implicaría que quedaría "desactualizado" tan pronto como la página original cambiara), o bien actuara como *proxy inverso*, haciendo una petición a la página original para después devolverle el contenido al navegador. Esta segunda opción sería un gran riesgo de seguridad, puesto que el "acortador de URLs" estaría actuando como *hombre en el medio*, enterándose de tus peticiones a la página y de las respuestas del servidor. Además sería imposible hacerlo si la comunicación fuese HTTPS, pues el certificado correcto lo tiene el servidor original y no el "hombre en el medio". El proxy podría terminar la conexión SSL con el cliente y hacer una nueva con el destino final, pero entonces la encriptación ya no iría *end-to-end* (es decir, desde el cliente hasta el servidor verdadero), sino que iría cifrada en dos tramos: del cliente al proxy y del proxy al servidor original, pero en el proxy se descifraría, con lo que de nuevo éste tendría acceso a información confidencial. Yo no usaría ese servicio.

Comment: Lo de seguridad no es problema, ya que es para un proyecto propio, páginas propias, no para el público.

Comment: @interactivo Entonces, si es para ti mismo ¿por qué quieres ocultar la URL real y cambiarla por la acortada? Si sólo lo vas a ver tú, qué más da. Respecto a qué lenguaje te permitiría hacer esto, mejor eliminas eso de la pregunta, pues puede causar que te la cierren por estar "basada en opiniones" y de todas formas es bastante irrelevante, ya que esto puede hacerse con cualquiera de los lenguajes habituales: java, javascript, python, C#, PHP, ... y decidir cuál es mejor sí que es una cuestión de opiniones.

Comment: Cuestiones privadas... He buscado hacerlo con Javascript pero no aparece soluciones, por eso dije que lenguajes lo permiten.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta es si, se podría hacer. La manera fácil y que no funciona con todos los dominios es utilizar `iframes`. En el ejemplo de abajo la página de **Bootstrap** permite insertar pero **Google** no. El motivo de esto es que los servidores pueden responder a la petición del iframe con la cabecera `X-Frame-Options` denegandola (más información sobre esto en [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

```
<iframe src="https://getbootstrap.com/"
id="iFramePosible"
    title="Bootstrap"
    width="500"
    height="200"
></iframe>

<iframe src="https://google.com"
id="iFrameimposible"
    title="stackoverflow"
    width="500"
    height="200"
></iframe>
```

Puedes verlo en funcionamiento en https://jsfiddle.net/logico/md3bLy8a/

La otra opción y que podría funcionar con todos los servidores es utilizar un proxy inverso.

1. El servidor `bit.ly` recibe la petición de `cliente` con la URL acortada.
2. `bit.ly` busca en la base de datos por la URL larga (`test.com`).
3. Luego el servidor `bit.ly` hace la petición al servidor `test.com`.
4. `test.com` responde a `bit.ly`
5. `bit.ly` responde a `cliente` con la respuesta de `test.com` desde la URL acortada.

No hay problema con SSL porque (si todos tienen certificados válidos) `cliente` tiene una comunicación segura con `bit.ly` y `bit.ly` tiene una conexión segura con `test.com`. Un sistema así se podría hacer con NodeJS, ExpressJS y una base datos, pero con cualquier lenguaje web puede ser posible. PoC ([extraído de aquí](https://codeforgeek.com/reverse-proxy-using-expressjs/))

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var serverOne = 'https://google.com',
    ServerTwo = 'https://bootstrap.com',
    ServerThree = 'https://logico.com.ar';

app.all("/app1/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server1');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});

app.all("/app2/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server2');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: ServerTwo});
});

app.all("/app2/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server3');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: ServerThree});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Documentación de [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy)

Comment: Aunque no haya problemas de SSL, hay un problema de seguridad importante. El usuario estará hablando con bit.ly y el certificado será del bit.ly. Pero verá en cambio la página de test.com que le podrá pedir contraseñas y datos sensibles, que estarían pasando a través de bit.ly y a los que bit.ly tendría acceso (y puede descifrar), pues debe terminar la conexión SSL y crear una nueva con test.com. En otras palabras, el cifrado ya no sería end-to-end entre el cliente y test.com, sino que bit.ly haría de hombre en el medio.

Comment: El OP pregunta específicamente sobre la posibilidad y que lenguaje utilizar para realizar un proyecto. Cuando pregunte sobre las implicaciones de usar proxys reversos respondere con otros argumentos.

Comment: puede ser mas sencillo teniendo un acortador de direcciones inhouse onda https://yourls.org/ de esa manera se mantiene en el dominio y puede o iframear o curl y replace de content link y scripts

Comment: alo Malbarez Y cómo se haría eso?